# C# WSDL requst/response in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, soap, request

I need help on how to create a client for the web service described by a WSDL. In my concrete example, the WSDL is located at:
http://philips.xpos.eu/integration/wsdl

The client should include the possibility to call the function `setSparePartPrice`.

I have tried adding a service reference in Visual Studio, however I am unable to call the respective function and obtain the response.

Comment: Please be more specific on the error that you receive and provide the steps with which the error can be reproduced. Potentially, include a minimal example of a simpler web service created by yourself after following some tutorials, e.g. https://www.technical-recipes.com/2017/creating-and-consuming-a-web-service-in-c-net/. If you are new to a certain technology, attempt to start with tutorials and smaller examples.

Comment: I now get this error calling a function.

A object of type philips.response_code[] can not be confered a object of type philips.spare_part_list_item_values[].

In documentation it says that this function getSparePartList returns a list of spare_part_list_item_values, but when calling the function I can only use: out response_code[]

Is this some kind casting I need to do? Here is my code:

String key = "TEST";
philips.XPOS_Service service = new philips.XPOS_Service();
philips.response_code[] responce_code_list = null;
service.getSparePartList(key, "", out responce_code_list);

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be resolvable by casting. The two types seem rather different. I assume the method `getSparePartList` has a different argument list than you are using. Why don't you supply a spare_part_list_item_values[] array to the out parameter instead of the response_code?